# BootStrap Tab: Background image inside tag not streching to 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I set a background image to `Bootstrap Tab` but the image is coming at the center and not covering the whole `Tab`. I tried using `backgroundSize` as `100%, cover, auto` etc but its of no use. I want the pink image to cover the whole tab. Please help

[image]

```
let tabStyle1 = {
  display: 'inline-block',
  width: 12,
  height: 15,
  backgroundColor: '#FF00FF', // added to check the issue
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + filename + ') ',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  backgroundPosition: '-0px -10px',
  backgroundSize: '15px 300px'
};
let tab1 = <img src={"./international-emoji/blank.gif"} style={ tabStyle1 }/>
 <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1}>

    <Tab eventKey={1} title={tab1}>
      <ul className="list-panel">
        ...
      </ul>
    </Tab>
```

Comment: Check its parent .May b some where parent property is getting override.?

Comment: Where's the code? Show us your code example.

Comment: @Paran0a Editied with the code

Comment: @suresh I checked it, nothing gets overridden

Answer (score 0):

When we attached background on CSS file or style then **we need to give proper width and height or required width and height** on that tag.

Comment: On changing the `width` and `height` using css, the width and height of Tab changes, I want the pink image to cover the Tab without altering the Tab size